# wet finger to smooth out silicone?

Tags: silicone

I have seen some tile guys wet their finger with saliva to smooth out a bead of silicone in a corner of a shower stall.  does this minor wetness have any adverse affects on the surface layer of the silicone or its ability to cure properly?

Comment: I suspect that the saliva helps avoid having too much caulk stick to the skin of your finger.

Answer (score 2):

It will not affect the curing of the silicone, but using a fine mist of denatured alcohol and smoothing out the caulk before the alcohol evaporates leaves a cleaner surface by removing all the residue from smoothing it out.

Answer (score 2):

It does not. However, if using 100% silicone it forms a skin (drying) very quickly and you will begin to "pull" the product vs smooth out. Consider using rubbing alcohol in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will cure properly.

Silicone is not water (or saliva) absorbent.

So it is only on the surface of the silicone.

Comment: actually, vinegar and spit mix pretty well...

Comment: I'm a bit lost, @dandavis, what does vinegar have to do with it?

Comment: @FreeMan it's the solvent used on silicon caulk; acetic acid,